# Access 2007 - Price Code from a Price Table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two tables. `members` and `codes`

I'm trying to get `members.price` to be automatically filled each time a new record is inserted - based on the code in `members.price_code`. It should match the `codes.code` and insert the correct `codes.price` in to `members.price`

I also need to do this for any existing members that currently have their codes set correctly, but the `price` field is empty

**My members table:**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦═════════════╦═══════╗
║ id ║  name        ║ price_code  ║ price ║
╠════╬══════════════╬═════════════╣═══════║
║  1 ║ John Doe     ║    M        ║   ?   ║
║  2 ║ Jane Doe     ║    M        ║   ?   ║
║  3 ║ Peter Doe    ║    S        ║   ?   ║
║  4 ║ Lisa Doe     ║    M        ║   ?   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩═════════════╩═══════╝
```

**My Codes table**

```
╔══════╦═══════════════╦═══════╗
║ code ║  description  ║ price ║
╠══════╬═══════════════╬═══════╣
║  M   ║ Member        ║  100  ║
║  S   ║ Student       ║  50   ║
╚══════╩═══════════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: you don't need to save price twice, just link the table by code and price is always accessible.

Comment: Yes I've noticed that too. So basically when I run a query that fetches the member with id:1, I need to get the code.price for that member

Comment: How do you insert new data? Using a form? To select the appropiate price, you can create a query joining both tables on price_code (straight forward query, you should be able to write that query yourself).